# Apply Custom Model Binder to Object Property in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I am trying to apply custom model binder for DateTime type property of model. 
Here is the IModelBinder and IModelBinderProvider implementations.

```
public class DateTimeModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(DateTime));
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{

    private string[] _formats = new string[] { "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy/MM/dd"
    , "yyyyMMddHHmm", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
    , "yyyyMMddHHmmss", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"};

    private readonly IModelBinder baseBinder;

    public DateTimeModelBinder()
    {
        baseBinder = new SimpleTypeModelBinder(typeof(DateTime), null);
    }

    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

            var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, _formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateTime))
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(dateTime);
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.TryAddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, $"{bindingContext} property {value} format error.");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        return baseBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);
    }
}
```

And here is the model class

```
public class Time
 {
        [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DateTimeModelBinder))]
        public DateTime? validFrom { get; set; }

        [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DateTimeModelBinder))]
        public DateTime? validTo { get; set; }
 }
```

And here is the controller action method.

```
[HttpPost("/test")]
public IActionResult test([FromBody]Time time)
{

     return Ok(time);
}
```

When tested, the custom binder is not invoked but the default dotnet binder is invoked. According to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#recommendations-and-best-practices),

> ModelBinder attribute could be applied to individual model properties
>   (such as on a viewmodel) or to action method parameters to specify a
>   certain model binder or model name for just that type or action.

But it seems not working with my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1. Reason**

According to the `[FromBody]Time time` in your action, I guess you're sending a payload with `Content-Type` of `application/json`. In that case, when a json payload received, the Model Binding System will inspect the parameter `time` and then try to find a proper binder for it. Because the `context.Metadata.ModelType` equals `typeof(Time)` instead of the `typeof(DateTime)`, and **there's no custom ModelBinder for `typeof(Time)`** , your `GetBinder(context)` method will return a `null` :

```
public class DateTimeModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(DateTime))     // not typeof(Time)
        {
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(DateTime));  
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Thus it **falls back to the default model binder for application/json**. The default json model binder uses `Newtonsoft.Json` under the hood and will simply deserialize the whole payload as an instance of `Time`. As a result, your `DateTimeModelBinder` is not invoked.

**2. Quick Fix**

One approach is to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (avoid using the `application/json`)

Remove the `[FromBody]` attribute:

```
[HttpPost("/test2")]
public IActionResult test2(Time time)
{
    return Ok(time);
}
```

and send the payload in the format of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
POST https://localhost:5001/test2
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

validFrom=2018-01-01&validTo=2018-02-02
```

It should work now.

**3. Working with JSON**

Create a custom converter as below :

```
public class CustomDateConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
         return true;
    }
    public static string[] _formats = new string[] { 
        "yyyyMMdd", "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy/MM/dd"
        , "yyyyMMddHHmm", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"
        , "yyyyMMddHHmmss", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
    };

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dt= reader.Value;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dt as string, _formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateTime)) 
            return dateTime;
        else 
            return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value as string);
    }
}
```

I simply copied your code to format the date.

Change your Model as below :

```
public class Time
{
    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DateTimeModelBinder))]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateConverter))]
    public DateTime? validFrom { get; set; }

    [ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DateTimeModelBinder))]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomDateConverter))]
    public DateTime? validTo { get; set; }
}
```

And now you can receive the time using `[FromBody]`

```
    [HttpPost("/test")]
    public IActionResult test([FromBody]Time time)
    {

        return Ok(time);
    }
```