# Implement IModelBinder for string collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding, custom-model-binder

Actually on my .NET Core project i'm using a simple modelbinder to trim input string

```
public class StringModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        ValueProviderResult valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult != ValueProviderResult.None)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

            string valueAsString = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(valueAsString) ? null : valueAsString.Trim();

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(valueAsString);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I use it through the IModelBinderProvider and it works perfectly on input of type string. However I notice that it's not fired when on input I have a collection of string like this

```
public IActionResult CollectionTrimTest([FromBody] List<string> values)
```

To perform it I think I should use something like

```
if (context.Metadata.IsCollectionType)
    return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(CollectionModelBinder));
```

but I really don't know how to implement CollectionModelBinder to trim result based on string collection. Centralizing the trim logic between StringModelBinder and CollectionModelBinder would be greatly appreciated of course.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, seems [FromBody] must require a JsonConverter. More information at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54663595/4963176